# System.InvalidOperationException: The current type, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration, is an interface and cannot be constructed

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, unity-container

> System.InvalidOperationException: The current type, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

I am using unity with .NET Core, and the error above is being given at this line:

`container.RegisterInstance<IServiceA>(IoC.Resolve<IServiceB>());`

IServiceB is registered as such:

```
container.RegisterType<IServiceB, ServiceA>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

I have a class ServiceA that implements IService B as follows.

```
public class ServiceA : IServiceB
{
   private IConfiguration _configuration;

   public ServiceA(IConfiguration configuration): base(configReader)
   {
        _configuration = configuration;
   }

   public string someVariable => _configuration.GetSection("Section").GetSection("WantedKey").Value;
    ...
}
```

I am using *Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration* for the Configuration.

So I do not know how to map it because I am getting it from *Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration*.

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve it?

Comment: Did you register an implementation of `IConfiguration` with the container?

Comment: build a configuration and then register it with the container.

Comment: Instead of trying to inject the entire configuration service, construct and inject specific configuration objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a file like *config.json*

```
{
  "Section" : {
    "WantedKey" : "WantedValue"
  }
}
```

You would first need to build a configuration instance

```
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("config.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    .Build();
```

And register that with the container

```
container.RegisterInstance<IConfiguration>(config);
```

In order for `IConfiguration` to be available to be resolved.

Now ideally you really shouldn't be passing `IConfiguration` around for injection. It is usually accessed at the composition root to get settings for other dependencies. Try to avoid coupling to external framework dependencies.

In this case you would want to create a strong type to hold the desired settings

```
public class MySetting {
    public string WantedKey { get; set; }
}
```

And populate an instance of it from configuration

```
MySetting setting = config.GetSection("Section").Get<MySetting>();
```

You would register that with the container

```
container.RegisterInstance<MySetting>(setting);
```

and have that injected into dependents

```
public class ServiceA : IServiceB {
    private readonly MySetting setting;

    public ServiceA(MySetting setting) {
        this.setting = setting;
    }

    public string someVariable => setting.WantedKey;
    //...
}
```

Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Thank you. This is a complete answer. I did not register IConfiguration. Actually my ServiceA class from above is a config class, like MySetting in your example, and in MySetting wouldn't I have to access config like the below? 

  ` private IConfiguration _configuration;`

   public ServiceA(IConfiguration configuration): base(configReader)
   {
        _configuration = configuration;
   }`

Comment: @Cookie no. like i said you want to avoid injecting that interface if possible. The suggested approach is to extract what is needed in the composition root and populate a strongly typed model.